# Distribute a header table value to another table several rows with the same id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with SQL Server on how to distribute a header table value to another table several rows with the same id : -

Table A :  -

```
Id |   Value  
---+--------
1  |   40    
2  |   21
```

Table B :  -

```
Id |   Qty    
---+-------
1  |   20     
1  |   13     
2  |   1
```

Result should be : -

```
Id | Value |   Qty 
--------------------
1  |   20  |   20  
1  |   20  |   13  
2  |   21  |   1
```

Comment: This looks like a simple join, not any kind of distribution. There's no header either. The first result should be `40`, not `20`

Comment: i am talking about value distribution on table b of table a where a.id=b.id

Comment: You didn't show any kind of distributiion. A simple `select * from A inner join b on A.Id=B.ID` will return the results you want

Comment: see Value i need equal value against id

Answer (score 0):

This below logic will distribute the value equally to all rows.

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT Value FROM A WHERE A.id = B.id)/COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY id) Value
FROM B
```

Output is-

```
Id  Qty Value
1   13  20
1   20  20
2   1   21
```

But if you wants to distribute the same value for all rows, do this below-

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT Value FROM A WHERE A.id = B.id) Value
FROM B
```

OR

```
SELECT B.*,A.Value
FROM B
INNER JOIN A ON B.id= A.id
```

Output will be-

```
Id  Qty Value
1   20  40
1   13  40
2   1   21
```

Comment: If i have 1 L records upper query will be slow because we are using query in select statement

Comment: What is your actual requirement? Distribute 40 among rows? or just add 40 to each row with the same id?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH TblA
     AS (SELECT 1 AS id, 
                40 AS num
         UNION
         SELECT 2, 
                21),
     TblB
     AS (SELECT 1 AS id, 
                20 AS num
         UNION
         SELECT 1, 
                13
         UNION
         SELECT 2, 
                1)
     SELECT *
     FROM TblA a
          INNER JOIN TblB b ON a.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this simple Join

```
SELECT ta.id, 
       ta.value / (SELECT ( Count(tmp.id) ) 
                   FROM   tb AS tmp 
                   WHERE  tmp.id = ta.id 
                   GROUP  BY tmp.id) AS 'value', 
       tb.qty 
FROM   ta 
       INNER JOIN tb 
               ON ta.id = tb.id
```

Full example (check Image):

```
CREATE TABLE ta 
  ( 
     id    INT, 
     value INT 
  ) 

CREATE TABLE tb 
  ( 
     id  INT, 
     qty INT 
  ) 

INSERT INTO ta 
VALUES      (1,40), 
            (2,21) 

SELECT * 
FROM   ta 

INSERT INTO tb 
VALUES      (1,20), 
            (1,13), 
            (2,1) 

SELECT * 
FROM   tb 

SELECT * 
FROM   ta 

SELECT * 
FROM   tb 

SELECT ta.id, 
       ta.value / (SELECT ( Count(tmp.id) ) 
                   FROM   tb AS tmp 
                   WHERE  tmp.id = ta.id 
                   GROUP  BY tmp.id) AS 'value', 
       tb.qty 
FROM   ta 
       INNER JOIN tb 
               ON ta.id = tb.id
```

[image]

Comment: In result value should be 20 for id 1

Comment: @NiteeshKumar,please check updated solution for your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Substitute table variables @Header & @Detail with your tables and remove the insert statements. You could also do this with a sub query to your main query as proposed in some of the other answers but for larger tables it may become slow hence the table variable called @Counter to first gather the aggregated count based on the @Detail table variable.

```
declare @Header table
(
    Id int identity(1, 1),
    [Value] int
)

declare @Detail table
(
    Id int identity(1, 1),
    HeaderId int,
    Qty int
)

declare @Counter table
(
    HeaderId int,
    [Count] int
)

insert into @Header values (40)
insert into @Header values (21)

insert into @Detail values (1, 20)
insert into @Detail values (1, 13)
insert into @Detail values (2, 1)

insert into @Counter
select d.HeaderId, count(d.HeaderId)
from @Detail d
group by d.HeaderId 

select 
    h.Id,
    h.[Value] / c.[Count] [Value],
    d.Qty
from @Header h 
join @Detail d
on h.Id = d.HeaderId
join @Counter c
on h.Id = c.HeaderId
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use a window function to divide the value:

```
select  tb.id, ta.value / count(*) over (partition by ta.id) as value, tb.qty
from ta join
     tb
     on ta.id = tb.id;
```

Note that because these are integers, you might want to avoid integer division by using:

```
select  tb.id, ta.value * 1.0 / count(*) over (partition by ta.id) as value, tb.qty
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=20f51f650105005b6648cf326a65fa0a) is a db<>fiddle.